# Creation of one AR causes creation of another AR

Tags: domain-driven-design

In DDD, is it okay if creation of one AR forces creation of another AR?  Take for example:

```
class User
{
  // User related functins
}

class Schedule
{
  // Schedule related functions
}

class Scheduler
{
  private ScheduleRepository repo; // injected

  public void Schedule(User user, Event event)
  {
    Schedule schedule = repo.FindByUser(user);
    schedule.Add(event);
    repo.Save(schedule);
  }
}
```

There is a 1:1 mapping between user and schedule.  When a user is created they need to have a schedule.  I cannot see why a schedule would exist without a user.  Additionally, when a user is removed from the roster/database, I still want their old schedule to persist in the scheduling database.

The User object will not have a reference to their actual schedule.  You would have to use the Scheduler object to actually schedule the event.  User would have a private ID and numerous Identity properties such as 'Name', 'Email', etc.

Am I overcomplicating this?  Additionally, when a user is created, I would assume I would need to query the UserRepository to get the ID (PK?) to associate with the Schedule object.

Comment: `I cannot see why a schedule would exist without a user. Additionally, when a user is removed from the roster/database, I still want their old schedule to persist in the scheduling database.` this is contradictory. Isn't It?

Comment: @Laiv, yes I suppose so.  Initially, when a user is created, I believe a schedule should also be created.  It's only when a user is removed that the schedule can exist without a user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creation patterns are weird....

> In DDD, is it okay if creation of one AR forces creation of another AR?

"It depends", which is part of the problem.

Aggregates, as described Evan's in the blue book, are *consistency boundaries*;  you use the aggregate root to manipulate the state encapsulated within that boundary, and thereby ensure that it is always in a self consistent state.

This works great if you are single threaded.

When you are multi-threaded, you now have an additional concern: to ensure that one thread doesn't clobber writes made in another thread.  In other words, you need to start thinking about *transaction* boundaries, and data races.

In particular, if you have *one* transaction that tries to update aggregates that are stored in *different* persistence structures, then you have two phase commit to worry about.

This has lead a number of people to the conclusion that aggregates should be in alignment with transaction boundaries as well, which is to say that a modification to an aggregate should never be allowed to change data that might be stored separately.

In effect, this pushes the orchestration of the (potential) two phase commit *back into the domain model*, where you can manage it explicitly (process managers/sagas).  Implemented in this fashion, your processes start to look more like the domain model pattern described [by Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html)

Imagine, for example, that the UserRepository and the ScheduleRepository are two different in memory collections.  You write to the first one, you write to the second, oops, that failed, you try to undo the write to the first... which already has additional changes written into it that you now need to worry about....

When your persistence store is a relational model (which was frequently the case in the early 2000s when Evans was writing), you can use something like a UnitOfWork pattern to manage the disconnect -- if the two collections are stored together.  You can achieve something similar with in memory collections, if you work at it enough, although you get the same sorts of contention concerns.

> Additionally, when a user is removed from the roster/database, I still want their old schedule to persist in the scheduling database.

You may want to review Udi Dahan's essay [Don't Delete -- Just Don't](http://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/)

Answer (score 1):

> In DDD, is it okay if creation of one AR forces creation of another AR?

Yes, it is OK. You may encounter this when you try to apply [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) to Aggregates.

> Additionally, when a user is removed from the roster/database, I still want their old schedule to persist in the scheduling database.

This is another indication that you need two separate Aggregates.

However, keep in mind that, because you have two Aggregates, you have eventual consistency *between* them, this means that it could *take a while* before the second Aggregate is created. An Aggregate can ensure only its own consistency.

As [@VoiceOfUnreason](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/364472/236092) said, the creation of the second Aggregate may fail and your system should not panic when this happens. One solution to cope with this situation is to model the creation of the two Aggregates as a [Saga/Process manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx). This Saga would have the responsibility that, eventually, the second Aggregate gets created (i.e by retrying or by notifying an Administrator to take some action).